# DJI Mavic Mini - excess arm vibration

Tags: dji-mavic-mini

I recently noticed while flying my Mavic Mini that its front right arm vibrates loudly while descending. Especially when I start to descend, the arm visibly vibrates and makes a low-pitched sound as opposed to the normal high-pitched buzzing. Is this an issue?

I checked the screws holding the props on - they're tight enough, and the props are only slightly chipped (much of the silver stripes on the end is still there), and that goes for all of the props, not just this one.

Could someone tell me what's going on / how to fix this? I'm concerned the drone will fall out of the sky if something breaks loose.

Comment: Is it a normal descent rate? Are you descending straight down?

Comment: Yes, its a normal descent rate. It's specifically when the props slow down at all that this happens.

Comment: That’s odd! I have no idea what’s causing that. I’m pretty interested myself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the problem. One of the props on that arm only was warped, causing irregular airflow and vibrating the arm. I changed out that prop and the issue disappeared.

Comment: 'new' vibration is nearly always the prop or motor screws, so you checked all the right things. If you're not sure about prop damage, the easy option is to change the prop and see if the vibration gets better.